# WSO2IS + node.js passport-saml integration error

Tags: node.js, wso2, passport.js, saml, wso2-identity-server

i'm now trying to test SAML2 integration by using wso2is server and node.js passport-saml module.
But it sees not working in wso2 side.

node.js server redirect to wso2 server with SAML assertion.
here is decoded SAML request assestion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_e62f87ab1740cab74c67" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-06-16T01:16:54.199Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:3000/login/callback" Destination="https://localhost:9443/samlsso">
   <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">passport-saml</saml:Issuer>
   <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
   </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
   <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

after i put user id/password in wso2 log in screen.
i got a error

SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On

Error when processing the authentication request!

Does anybody can give an opinion about this?

in wso2is configuration

SP is registered and i only set up Inbound authentication configuration > SAML2 Web SSO Configuration > Issuer : passport-saml. 
Assertion consumer URL : http: //localhost:3000/login/callback

Here is node.js code

```
var express = require('express')
  , passport = require('passport-debug')
  , util = require('util')
  , SamlStrategy = require('../../lib/passport-saml/index').Strategy
  , fs = require('fs');


var users = [
    { id: 1, givenName: 'bob', email: 'bob@example.com' }
  , { id: 2, givenName: 'joe', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];

function findByEmail(email, fn) {
  for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.email === email) {
      return fn(null, user);
    }
  }
  return fn(null, null);
}


// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  findByEmail(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',

    //protocol: 'http://',
    //cert: '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'/*,
    //privateCert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem', 'utf-8')*/
  },
  function(profile, done) {
    console.log("Auth with", profile);
    if (!profile.email) {
      return done(new Error("No email found"), null);
    }
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          // "Auto-registration"
          users.push(profile);
          return done(null, profile);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));

var app = express.createServer();

// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/error', failureFlash: true,samlFallback:'login-request' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/idc');
  }
);

app.post('/login/callback',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/idc');
  }
);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server listening in http://localhost:3000");
});

// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
//   Use this route middleware on any resource that needs to be protected.  If
//   the request is authenticated (typically via a persistent login session),
//   the request will proceed.  Otherwise, the user will be redirected to the
//   login page.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

---

additional comment.
After i fixed node.js code.
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(

```
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    protocol: 'http://'
```

wso2 (idp) response SAML response assertion to node.js passport-saml callback module
Here is SAML response assertion from wso2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://localhost:3000/login/callback" ID="nnjiingggcmkbagmbndjpcaignnlkcickjadcomp" InResponseTo="_4ca6c18350670c605fa7" IssueInstant="2014-06-16T01:55:28.312Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </saml2p:Status>
   <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="bpplnakjbmabobeeimjihmelgdebhgcinikjfped" IssueInstant="2014-06-16T01:55:28.312Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
      <saml2:Subject>
         <saml2:NameID>admin</saml2:NameID>
         <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_4ca6c18350670c605fa7" NotOnOrAfter="2014-06-16T02:00:28.312Z" Recipient="http://localhost:3000/login/callback" />
         </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml2:Subject>
      <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2014-06-16T01:55:28.312Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-06-16T02:00:28.312Z">
         <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml2:Audience>passport-saml</saml2:Audience>
         </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml2:Conditions>
      <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-06-16T01:55:28.312Z">
         <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
         </saml2:AuthnContext>
      </saml2:AuthnStatement>
   </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

but i got a error from passport-saml side like this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 16 Jun 2014 01:55:28 GMT] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 1282 "-"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chr
ome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
SAML:authentication has benn called
SAML:authenticate:error:[object Object]
SAML:authenticate:error:[object Object]
SAML authenticate:PostResponse[object Object]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Format' of undefined
    at C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\lib\passpo
rt-saml\saml.js:425:24
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pass
port-saml\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:384:20)
    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Object.onclosetag (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passp
ort-saml\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:348:26)
    at emit (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\node
_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:615:33)
    at emitNode (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\
node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:620:3)
    at closeTag (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\
node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:861:5)
    at Object.write (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-s
aml\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1294:29)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:403:31)
    at Parser.parseString (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pass
port-saml\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:6:61)
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 16 Jun 2014 01:55:28 GMT] "POST /login/callback HTTP/1.1" 50
0 1310 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
```

It is little weired that, in WSO2is server SAML assertion response.

```
<saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
```

I coded Issuer as "passport-saml" but in the SAML response it has been changed to localhost
do u have any idea on this?

[image: wso2IS configuration]

---

added comment.
in SAML Response attribue "Format" was missing in  element.

```
<saml2:NameID>admin</saml2:NameID>
```

So i changed configuration in WSO2 SAML configuration.
I added "NameID format" with "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
After that it seems works.
In addition, in SAML response, it doesn't send "email" in SAML response assertion, i did small code change like below. (instead of using email, it uses user id)

```
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    protocol: 'http://',
    //identifierFormat :'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress'
    identifierFormat :'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity'
    //cert: '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'/*,
    //privateCert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem', 'utf-8')*/
  },
  function(profile, done) {
    console.log("Auth with", profile);
    console.log('Name Id',profile.nameID);
    if (!profile.nameID) {
      return done(new Error("No nameId found"), null);
    }
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      findByEmail(profile.nameID, function(err, user) {
            console.log('User ',user);
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          // "Auto-registration"
          users.push(profile);
          return done(null, profile);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));
```

but i still got a error in passport-SAML

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 16 Jun 2014 02:38:05 GMT] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 1322 "-"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chr
ome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
SAML:authentication has benn called
SAML:authenticate:error:[object Object]
SAML:authenticate:error:[object Object]
SAML authenticate:PostResponse[object Object]
SAML:authenticate:errornull
Auth with { issuer:
   { _: 'localhost',
     '$': { Format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity' } },
  nameID: 'admin',
  nameIDFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity' }
Name Id admin
User  { id: 1, givenName: 'bob', email: 'admin' }

TypeError: object is not a function
    at pass (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-debug\lib
\passport\index.js:249:14)
    at Passport.serializeUser (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
passport-debug\lib\passport\index.js:251:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\passport-saml\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:48:29)
    at Context.delegate.success (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\passport-debug\lib\passport\middleware\authenticate.js:194:13)
    at Context.actions.success (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\passport-debug\lib\passport\context\http\actions.js:21:25)
    at verified (C:\Users\bw.cho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\passport-saml\
lib\passport-saml\strategy.js:55:14)
    at C:\dev\workspaces\node_js\SAML2\app.js:68:16
    at findByEmail (C:\dev\workspaces\node_js\SAML2\app.js:17:14)
    at C:\dev\workspaces\node_js\SAML2\app.js:58:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem.
After replace "passport-debug" module to "passport" module, it works
full source code is https://github.com/bwcho75/node.js_study/tree/master/WSO2SAML2
enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the part about why the format attribute was required on the subject name -- it's a bug, which I've filed at https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/issues/40.

Glad to hear you got it working!